# Как указать пользовательские стили в Vue good table

Tags: css, vue.js

Работаю на таблицей с заказами. Для построения таблицы использую Vue Good Table. В ней есть базовые стили такие как .vgt-table.
Я хочу указать свои стили для этой таблицы и поэтому описываю их в секции style компонента, однако мои стили игнорируются. Как быть?

Comment: Быть как изучающий специфичность CSS-селекторов. Если базовые стили не перекрываются, значит их приоритет выше... и значит, надо повысить приоритет перекрывающих (повышением специфичности в первую очередь).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь 